# При публикации собранного приложения Vue на GitHub Pages на странице вылезают ошибки 404

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Такая проблема:
При публикации собранного приложения Vue на GitHub Pages на странице вылезают ошибки 404 на все файлы, на которые ссылается приложение - то есть на те, что получились после сборки, js и css, соответственно на странице ничего не отображается. Тестировал локально, локально все отображается. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, разобрался! Дело и было как раз в publicPath, сайт пытался взять контент из папок css и js в корне сайта, а для gh pages нужно добавить еще название репозитория. Добавил его в publicPath и все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно вы ошиблись вероятно публикации

https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

К тому же, если вы публикуете приложение с роутером, то вам нужно его настроить, как написано в документации.
Дело в том, что vue изначально предполагает, что вы разместите приложение в корне домена, поэтому когда вы переходите по ссылкам, вас маршурутизирует на 404 github. Убедитесь, что вы сделали все верно и все заработает.

Comment: У меня простое приложение без роутера и локально все запускает. В итоге github pages выводит файл index.html, там есть div#app но больше ничего, и в консоле 5 ошибок 404, на app.d354cea3.css, chunk-vendors.49f69c55.css, app.b5775a31.js, chunk-vendors.573e425b.js, app.b5775a31.js, то есть на те файлы, что vue билдит. Не могу понять в чем дело. publicPath установлен по умолчанию '/', ничего вроде больше не должно влиять, опять так с локального сервера запускает нормально все

Comment: @IliaSafin ссылку на ваш github pages пожалуйста

Comment: да, конечно, вот [github pages](https://showcasepro.online/)